# How can I determine the Docker image used by a SageMaker Endpoint created with JumpStart

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, artificial-intelligence, amazon-sagemaker, large-language-model

I have created an LLM Endpoint using the SageMaker Jumpstart Service. I've tested it out, and everything works great. But where should I check which Docker image is used?

For instance, in the Endpoint Configuration, I can only find these variables:

```
Key                                                     Value


sagemaker:user-profile-arn                               My User id
    
aws-jumpstart-inference-model-uri                        s3://jumpstart-cache-prod-us-east-1/meta-infer/infer-meta-textgeneration-llama-2-7b.tar.gz

sm-jumpstart-monitor                                     True

sm-jumpstart-id                                          JumpStart ID

sagemaker:domain-arn                                     domain
```

I do need the docker image to deploy Endpoint via CloudFormation.

Regards,
Volodymyr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon SageMaker JumpStart is just a quick way to start a regular endpoint.

Got to the relevant Model - In the console, select SageMaker service, then in the left tab, open Inference and Model.

In the model configuration, you should see **Image** URI.

Comment: Not always, for some endpoints that data isn't available so you need to find it somewhere else.